# date conversion from DD/MM/YYYY HH:MM:SS to YYYYMM

Tags: oracle, date

i want to convert date to some other format.

Below is the example `04/03/10 09:00:50.000000000 AM`to YYYYMM

Iam not able to get this , below is the query which i used to convert.

```
select to_char(to_date('04/03/10 09:00:50.000000000 AM','MM/DD/YYYY HH:MM:SS AM'),'YYYYMM') from table;
```

Iam getting exception as below

**ORA-01810: format code appears twice
01810. 00000 -  "format code appears twice"**

Answer (score 11, accepted):

1. Format Code for Minutes is MI, not MM. MM is for months.
2. You are using 2-digit year. Better to use RR for this. Even better use 4-digit year.
3. TO_DATE doesn't store fractional seconds. You need to use TO_TIMESTAMP and use the FF as format code.

So, your query would be

```
select to_char(to_timestamp('04/03/10 09:00:50.000000000 AM','MM/DD/RR HH:MI:SS.FF9 AM'),'YYYYMM') 
from table;
```

Answer (score 0):

To achieve your goal there are many issues to resolve ;)
Finally I made this like that:

```
select to_char(
         to_timestamp('04/03/10 09:00:50.000000000 AM','MM/DD/YYYY HH:MI:SS.FF9 PM',
                      'nls_date_language = ENGLISH'),
                      'YYYYMM') from dual;
```